# Huge amount of TransientErrors when trying to add tasks to task queue (push)

Tags: google-app-engine

My app (gqueues-hrd) is seeing a HUGE amount of TransientErrors when trying to add tasks with the task queue API.  Every request fails, actually.

I have changed nothing on my end with my app in weeks.  Can someone PLEASE investigate?  This has made my app completely unusable and I have lots of vocal, angry customers.

"/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/taskqueue.py", line 1637, in add self._*AddTasks(tasks, transactional, self.*_FillAddPushTasksRequest) File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/taskqueue.py", line 1680, in __AddTasks raise _TranslateError(e.application_error, e.error_detail) TransientError

Thanks,
Cameron

Comment: same here. must be an infrastructure issue at Google.

Comment: Well after 45 minutes of downtime things seem to be working again.  Hopefully it holds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem at the google's end.
as per their status: "The problem with the Google App Engine Task Queue API should be resolved as of 10:40 AM US/Pacific time."
https://code.google.com/status/appengine/detail/taskqueue/2012/12/18#ae-trust-detail-taskqueue-add-latency

Answer (score 0):

The same here...

File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/labs/taskqueue/taskqueue.py", line 1042, in add
    queue_name=queue_name, transactional=transactional)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/labs/taskqueue/taskqueue.py", line 717, in add
    return Queue(queue_name).add(self, transactional=transactional)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/labs/taskqueue/taskqueue.py", line 803, in add
    self.__AddTasks(tasks, transactional)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/labs/taskqueue/taskqueue.py", line 836, in _*AddTasks
    raise self.*_TranslateError(e.application_error, e.error_detail)
TransientError

Is is back and working almost 1hr later!

On GAE Engine Status:

10:00 AM - 11:59 PM 
Taskqueue

Problems adding tasks
We're investigating an issue with Google App Engine Task Queue service beginning at 10 AM US/Pacific time. We will provide more information shortly.